# Extra mouse click 30 pixels + on the X

Tags: windows-10, script, mouse-click

What I need is a script that will run in Windows 10 that will cause a second click a constant number of pixels to the right (or left) after clicking the left mouse button once. Any ideas?

The following image shows the required outcome - each red dot representing 1 mouse click

[image: Example]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I need both points to be at exact same Y coordinate on the screen. While processing this drafting in AutoCAD (matter directly connected to OVERKILL command) if selecting both points by hand Y is never the same, hence overkill command don't work and duplicates are not deleted. I am trying to save a lot of time here.